# How to sort an NSMutableArray of playing cards using number wise

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have an NSMutableArrary, it has the image of playing cards like as:

01-13 cards are Spades,
14-26 are Hearts,
27-39 are Diamonds,and
40-52 are Clubs.

I sort it by Color using this code,

```
[CopyArraryForShorting sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

but I'm fail to sort it arrary by Number. Please tell me how to sort it.

```
arrayPlayerCard=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"04.png"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"05.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"06.png"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"07.png"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"08.png"],........,nil];
```

Comment: What order do you expect after the sort, I actually don't understand, please provide an example.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it sorted so that you get all the aces, then all the twos, etc? So you'd get something like (pseudocode) [AH, AS, AD, AC, 2H, 2S, 2D, 2C, 3H, 3S...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the cards sorted in strict numerical order, regardless of suit. So all the aces, then all the twos, and so on.

If possible, I'd suggest you model a card class that has member variables for value and suit. When you model your data appropriately, the obvious use cases tend to be easy to address. The fact that it's a struggle in this case is a good indication that the data model (strings with numeric values that don't necessarily mean anything outside this code) is a bad one.

Nevertheless, you may be stuck with the data model you have, in which case you can achieve a suit-insensitive sort by doing the following:

1. take the integer values of the numbers at the start of each filename
2. subtract one from those values, to make it a zero-based numbering system
3. use module 13 to get the card value (actually the card value minus one, but that's fine for sorting)
4. use the card value to compare

`sortUsingFunction` is your friend here. Here's a simple implementation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSInteger compareCardsByValue(id a, id b, void *context) {
    // Get the integer value of the number at the start
    // of the filename
    NSInteger a_int = [(NSString*)a integerValue];
    NSInteger b_int = [(NSString*)b integerValue];

    // For each of the integer values, subtract one (so
    // we have a zero-based numbering system), then get
    // the value of the integer modulo 13
    a_int = (a_int - 1) % 13;
    b_int = (b_int - 1) % 13;

    // if you want aces to be high:
    //if (a_int == 0) a_int = 13;        
    //if (b_int == 0) b_int = 13;        

    // Now compare and return the appropriate value
    if (a_int < b_int) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (a_int > b_int) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *arp = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Create a mutable array
    NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:52];

    // Generate 52 image names, 01.png to 52.png, and add
    // them to the array
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 52; i++) {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i.png", i];
        [a addObject:imageName];
    }

    // Sort using the compareCardsByValue function
    [a sortUsingFunction:compareCardsByValue context:NULL];

    // Print out the resulting array
    for (NSString *s in a) {
        NSLog(@"%@", s);
    }

    [arp drain];
    return 0;
}
```